# python 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, linux, centos

```
[root@proxy-001 scripts]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import MySQLdb
   >>> from MySQLdb import cursors
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 16, in <module>
        insert_values= re.compile(restr)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

any ideas?

Same error:

```
[root@proxy-001 scripts]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> import MySQLdb.cursors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 16, in <module>
    insert_values= re.compile(restr)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

edited: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py
added:

```
print re
print dir(re)
insert_values= re.compile(restr)


[root@proxy-001 scripts]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> import MySQLdb.cursors
<module 're' from 're.pyc'>
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'main', 'modify_url', 'sys']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 18, in <module>
    insert_values= re.compile(restr)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
>>>
```

Comment: you simply have `re.py` right in the directory where you type `python` or in the one of directories in `PYTHONPATH`.  Rename it and all should work correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's strange.  Do you have a module named "re.py" somewhere in your Python path which is shadowing the "real" re module?

UPDATE: Okay, based on your edit, I'm now certain that you have an re.py module which is shadowing the real one, and if I'm reading the path correctly, it's in the very directory you're calling the program from!  Did you write an re.py module which has one "modify_url" function?

Anyway, find that re.py -- it's probably in your scripts directory -- and rename it to something else.

Comment: i am able to import re, it gives error only when i call MySQLdb.cursors

Comment: Then could you add the lines "print re" and "print dir(re)" to cursors.py, right before the insert_values = re.compile(restr) command?  I think it's picking up an re.py from somewhere.

Comment: It does seem to import **something**, you'll get a different error if the the ``re`` module wasn't imported (``NameError: name 're' is not defined``). Does ``re.compile()`` work from the Python commandline?

Comment: Yes, that "import re" succeeds by itself doesn't tell us anything.  "print re" should tell us where it's from.

Comment: Added what? So typing ``re.compile()`` in the commandline gives the same error? What's the output of ``sys.modules`` after you've imported both ``re`` and ``sys``?

Comment: @krisdigitx: but what did it print out?  Could you paste that into your question?

Comment: sorry my fault...there was a re.py on the directory i was working on, i have renamed it and the import works fine...is there any way in python to tell it to ignore any modules to load if its in the current directory...this could solve problems like these..

Comment: You can remove ``''`` from ``sys.path``: ``sys.path.remove('')``, and (re)add it as the last argument in the list.